# resize root volume in yaml executes but does not resize in ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to add a section to a `yaml` that will allow the root volume of an `ec2` to be adjusted from the default `30`. If I launch the instance using the ec2 console I can resize from `30 to 200`, and the below does create an `ec2` but not with the adjusted root volume. Thank you :)

**yaml**

```
Parameters:
 BlockDeviceMappings:
  Type: Number
  Description: Root Volume Size
  Default: 40
RootDeviceName:
 Type: String
 Description: Volume Device Name
 Default: "/dev/xvda" 

Resources:
 VolumeAttachment:
   Type: AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment
   Properties:
   Device: !Ref RootDeviceName
   InstanceId: !Ref EC2
   VolumeId: !Ref RootVolume
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I describe a new EC2 instance to launch in CloudFormation, I use a LaunchTemplate. In the LaunchTemplateData, you can specify the BlockDeviceMappings there and link that in the EC2 resource.

I've added an example template below I've omitted some info for brevity.

```yaml
Resources:
  ec2Server:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref ec2LaunchTemplate
        Version: !GetAtt ec2LaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber

  ec2LaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: 'server-launch-template'
      LaunchTemplateData:
        IamInstanceProfile:
          Arn: ...
        ImageId: ...
        InstanceType: ...
        KeyName: ...
        BlockDeviceMappings:
          - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
            Ebs:
              VolumeSize: 64
              VolumeType: gp2
              DeleteOnTermination: true
```